# How to compute the coefficients of a polynomial given a vector containing the roots in R

Tags: r, polynomial-math

I want to compute the coefficients of a polynomial based on a vector containing the roots. I first defined a vector of coefficients:

```
pol <- c(0,1,2,3,4)
```

and computed the roots

```
roots <- polyroot(pol)
```

to have a test result.
Then i tried the following:

```
result <- 1
for (n in 1:(length(roots))){
result <- c(result, 0) + c(0,-roots[n]*result)
}
```

But the my result is the following:

```
result 
[1] 1.00+0i 0.75+0i 0.50+0i 0.25+0i 0.00+0i
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

```
identical(polyroot(pol), polyroot(pol / 4))
# [1] TRUE
```

That is, by going from a polynomial to its roots you lose information about the coefficient of the highest degree term (in this case, 4). For instance, 2x^2-x=2x(x-1/2), but also x^2-x/2=x(x-1/2), so that the roots are the same and we only normalized the first polynomial with respect to the quadratic term. So,

```
Re(result) * 4
# [1] 4 3 2 1 0
```

gives the result but also requires the knowledge of `tail(pol, 1)`.

Comment: @JimmyJim, does it answer your question?

Comment: yess thank you very much. Sorry that i forgot to respond.

Comment: @JimmyJim, great! I guess the answer can be accepted then.